# How to find Nearest Locations in Google Maps with radius and a particular area(without having Latitude & Longitude) as parameters in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

Hi i am trying to get the near by locations of a particular area surrounding 3 kms distance.

Here i am passing two parameters, 
1) one is radius i.e; surrounding 3 kms distance.
2) second is particular area without having latitude and longitudes values.

### For Example:

I have Countries, States, Cities and Areas in by SQL Server database.

I have 4 dropdowns boxes for selecting above data.

Now i will select Country-India, State-A.P, City-Hyderabad, Area-Banjara Hills.

I need to get my output with areas surrounding 3 kms from selected area.

Can anyone Please help me in solving this Problem.

Thanks, Chakri.

Answer (score 0):

Getting near by place without `Long`, `Lat` is not possible. Solution for your problem is simple.

1. Get Human Readable Location data from your DB(eg. City, State, Street)
2. Then query Google Map API, pass Human Readable Address, it will return `Lat, Long` 
   (eg. `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false`)
3. Now with `Lat, Long` received in Response, use them to query Google Map API to find near by places

Hope it's clear :)

Comment: Thank you Ishan Dhingra for your answer. Can you please tell me, the C# code for calling the above link from .aspx page.